# For integer $n$ prove that if there is no integer $m\le \sqrt{n}$ such that $ m | n$, then $n$ is prime.

Tags: logic, proof-verification

At first I thought that the best way to prove this statement is to take the direct approach and show the subset {1, 2, 3,...sqrt(n)} and the subset {sqrt(n),... n/3, ..., n/2,...,n} and show that every element in the first subset has a corresponding element in the second subset and therefore if an element doesn't have one member of its pair in the first subset then that doesn't form a legal matching pair and doesn't divide n, meaning that if all elements in the first subset don't divide n, then none of the elements in the greater set do.

Is this logic okay? Or should I instead consider trying to prove this by means of the contrapositive?

Comment: I think you should prove this both ways and then decide which proof you think is clearer or better. Good luck.

Comment: There is always an integer $m\le \sqrt{n}$ such that $m\mid n$, e.g., $m=1$ or $m=-1$.

Answer (score 0):

Your intuition is correct.

If $m \mid n$, then $\frac{n}{m} \mid n$. One of $m$ or $\frac{n}{m}$ must be greater than or equal to $\sqrt{n}$.

So suppose for contradiction that $n$ is composite *and* there does not exist an $m \leq \sqrt{n}$ such that $m \mid n$. Then, because $n$ is composite, there must be an $m'$ with $n > m' > \sqrt{n}$ and $m' \mid n$. Then show $\frac{m'}{n} \leq \sqrt{n}$.

Just be careful when constructing the sets that you mentioned in your question. $\sqrt{n}$ may not be an integer, so you will have to take a [floor or ceiling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions).